# I would like to ask about the sandbox. Can not create file?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sandbox

My program processing a file in a directory, then create another file in this directory. If you do not open the sandbox results are correct, if I open sandbox then create a file will fail. But I've seen some people can do it. Who can tell me how to do it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Answer (score 0):

A core purpose of the sandbox is to prevent an application from reading or writing files without the user giving their permission. Here are three ways to obtain the permission to write a file:

A) If your application is designed to process all the files in a directory, reading in existing files and writing out new ones then use a `NSOpenPanel` to have the user select the *directory*. This grants your application read/write/create to that directory. The user will be presented with a single dialog asking for the directory.

B) If you are processing a file selected by the user and then to produce a file with the *same* name, in the *same* directory, but with a *different* file extension (e.g. an application which converts files from one format to another) then you can use the *Related Items* feature of the sandbox. This requires you to list both file extensions in your applications `Info.plist`, add a boolean `NSIsRelatedItemType` flag to those `Info.plist` entries, and use `NSFileCoordinator` & `NSFilePresenter` classes - which a standard document based application does automatically. The user will see a single dialog asking for the source file.

C) You are processing a file and producing another with a *different* name or in a *different* directory. You need to use `NSOpenPanel` to access the file and `NSSavePanel` to obtain permission to write the result. The user will be presented with two dialogs.

Apple provide an overview in [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).

HTH

Comment: Thank you reply, you give three kinds of methods are needed to open the Save dialog box, and the program does not comply, the effect I want is: 
   Select the file in the finder and then pop up the context menu. Choose my application in the menu. Then create a new file. 

For example, select a rar file in the finder, right pop-up context menu select extract to the current directory. 
Like this https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/mini-unrar/id641146824?l=en&mt=12